# Send JSON Data to Browser but HIDE contents

Tags: php, html, json

I'm not sure if I'm getting this right, but I'll try to describe what I do. I've got a file with JSON data in it, which is needed for a synology package server, so if I add the url to the package server of the synology nas it accepts it as Package Server and reads the packages. This all depends on the JSON file and I need to set DirectoyIndex of my Apache to this JSON file to make it work. The Downside now is, everyone accessing this url with a browser can directly look into this JSON file.

Can I somehow wrap or hide this json data but still have it used by the NAS Package Server. IE using a index.php or index.html showing some kind of webpage but having the json data transferred too, when accessing the page?

Comment: You could try to deny every request that does not come from the server you want to allow. So that everybody accessing it from a browser will get denied but the package server you gave the url to will be able to read it

Comment: probably best to configure apache to allow only the NAS's IP access to that directory/url. there's no 100% reliable way of determining WHAT made an http request.

Comment: You could try restricting or redirecting based on user agent in .htaccess.  I don't know what user agent is set by the Synology package manager, but redirect anything else to some other url or simply DENY.